# How can consumers of a custom XCFramework access the header documentation?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcframework

I'm developing an XCFramework which has a lot of good documentation (as docstrings/Markup [Apple Markup Formatting Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Xcode/Reference/xcode_markup_formatting_ref/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016497-CH2-SW1)) for its public interface. However, when the framework is included in a client app, Xcode doesn't show any documentation when you Option-Click ("Quick Help") on a method or property.

Within the SDK.xcframework folder there is a file `Headers/SDK-Swift.h` which actually includes all of those documentation strings.

Is there a way to tell Xcode to use the shipped documentation?

My XCFramework is created via `xcodebuild -create-xcframework -framework x.framework -framework y.framework -output z.xcframework`

Comment: Did you come any further?

Comment: unfortunately no...